# JSC_REDECLARED_VARIABLE_ERROR when using gulp closure compiler plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, google-closure-compiler

I have been trying to use closure compiler to optimize and bundle a project for two weeks now. 
The project is originally written in TypeScript. So I wanted to use [Tsickle](http://%20%20%20https://github.com/angular/tsickle) to transpile to JS that would be easily fed to the closure compiler Java app. When I was finally able to do that I stumbled on external Node modules problems. I tried all the solutions I was able to find in Google Groups, SO and in the closure compiler repo. Nothing worked.

Wanting to not let this go I decided to use gulp. This is my gulpfile.js, I tried keeping it as simple as possible.

```js
const closureCompiler = require("google-closure-compiler").gulp();

gulp.task("js-compile", function () {
  return gulp
    .src("./src/**/*.js", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      closureCompiler(
        {
          compilation_level: "ADVANCED",
          warning_level: "VERBOSE",
          jscomp_off: "checkVars",
          js_output_file: "output.min.js"
        },
        {
          platform: ["native", "java", "javascript"]
        }
      )
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/js"));
});
```

There are way too many input files for me to put them. This time I used TSC instead of Tsickle to transpile.
The error when running gulp I get is

```
[JSC_REDECLARED_VARIABLE_ERROR] Illegal redeclared variable: *nameofvariable*
```

I have this for almost every file in my project, even if the name is not repeated twice in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [tscc](https://github.com/theseanl/tscc). It uses tsickle under the hood and provides some solutions to external node_modules problems.

Comment: I tried using tscc with both rollup and the spec file, not much luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Try `--env CUSTOM` or `--isolation_mode IIFE`. I ran into this when compiling code that conflicted with browser interfaces like `Node`.